# PHP catching thrown InvalidArgumentException from function

Tags: php

I am using a JWS library,to un-sign some tokens, so when the token was invalid I got the Exception `InvalidArgumentException`

> ({ "name": "Exception", "message": "The token \"123\" is an invalid JWS", "code": 0, "type": "InvalidArgumentException", "file": "/var/www/html/checkout/vendor/namshi/jose/src/Namshi/JOSE/J‌​WS.php", "line": 143,)

```
$jws= SimpleJWS::load($data);
```

The static function load throws an exception if the token is not valid, and I don't want to display the exception message, instead I want to display a friendly error message.

any help?

Comment: just use `try{} catch(invalidArgumentException $e ){}`

Comment: I tried this try {$jws= SimpleJWS::load($data);}catch(invalidArgumentException $e){echo $e->getMessage();} but not working!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
try {
    $jws= SimpleJWS::load($data);
// if it's the php exception http://php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php
} catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
// if it's the library's exception you should specify the complete namespace
//} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    //  token is not valid
}
```

Comment: Still not working ({
  "name": "Exception",
  "message": "The token \"123\" is an invalid JWS",
  "code": 0,
  "type": "InvalidArgumentException",
  "file": "/var/www/html/checkout/vendor/namshi/jose/src/Namshi/JOSE/JWS.php",
  "line": 143,)

Comment: thanks man, but why "\Exception" this works not "InvalidArgumentException" since the thrown exception is InvalidArgumentException?

Comment: your file is in a namespace so you need to use `\InvalidArgumentException`  to catch the exception of the base namespace. If you forget the `'\'` before the name, php will look for an InvalidArgumentException defined in the current namespace

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me

```
try {
    $jws= SimpleJWS::load($data);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    # Do something
}
```

Comment: I used only Exception, and wasn't working. With \Exception works.